# getting errors while crating dotnet(.Net) project from terminal in arch linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I`ve just installed dotnet,dotnet-runtime,vscode to build dotnet applications in my garuda Linux(it's a type of arch Linux).
when I'm trying to create a new project from the terminal with the command 'dotnet new counsole -o myfrist ' then I got this output.

```
╭─venkey at garuda0 in ⌁/Documents/vscode/snd
╰─λ dotnet new console -o fristapp
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on fristapp/fristapp.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
  Failed to restore /home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj (in 769 ms).
Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

even I executed this command still I got the bellow error.

```
╭─venkey at garuda0 in ⌁/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp
╰─λ dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
  Failed to restore /home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj (in 788 ms).
```

and when I try to run the code again I got this error.

```
╭─venkey at garuda0 in ⌁/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp
╰─λ dotnet run
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/home/venkey/Documents/vscode/snd/fristapp/fristapp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

with errors, I've unable to create any dotnet applications nor run the dotnet applications.
can anyone help to solve these errors and to crate dotnet applications?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the ca-certificates-mozilla package.
You can fix this by downgrading.
Version 3.62-1 works.